# Run two Versions of Windows In one PC

Tags: windows-xp

How can two versions of Windows run in one PC at a time?

Comment: The question is too vague.

Answer (score 7):

Quite simple - If you need to run them simultaneously, you can use a virtual machine software such as [virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/).

If its a dualboot, you simply repartition, and install the other version of windows, and the bootloader will pick it up automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention versions of windows you want to use at same time. Like previous comment, Virtual Box or VMWare Player (which is free) or VirtualPC from MS, is the best option. But if you don't want to use virtualization sofrware. You can dual-boot. For using XP with Vista or 7 we have to install XP 1st, then install vista or 7. You can use XP from boot menu of 7 or Vista.